# Paging 3 in android not working on initial load

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-3

I have a fragment "webpages" implemented in a search activity. The problem is that when I click to open the fragment the api request is sent through the load ftn in paging source and *I think the loader saves that data*,and the next time I click the button to open the fragment (in memory) *if the api has returned the response by then *  the response data shows in the recycler view, I really cant understand why it takes two clicks
**My code**

## WebPagesFragment

```
package com.example.browserapp.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.paging.LoadState
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.browserapp.R
import com.example.browserapp.adapters.WebpagesSearchAdapter
import com.example.browserapp.search.searchTerm
import com.example.browserapp.viewmodels.WebPagesViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class WebPagesFragment(private val btnBinding: Button) : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_web_pages) {
    private lateinit var rvSearchResult: RecyclerView
    private val viewModel: WebPagesViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var adapter: WebpagesSearchAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.query = searchTerm
        rvSearchResult = view.findViewById(R.id.rvWebpagesSearchResult)
        rvSearchResult.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvSearchResult.setHasFixedSize(true)

        adapter =
            WebpagesSearchAdapter(WebpagesSearchAdapter.DIFF_CALLBACK) // Use DiffUtil callback
        observePagingData()
        rvSearchResult.adapter = adapter
//        adapter.refresh()
//        viewModel.fetchWebSearchResults(searchTerm) // Trigger initial loading

    }

    private fun observePagingData() {
        Log.d("TAGINN2", "observe PAGING DATA ftn")
        adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
            // Handle loading and error states
            Log.d("TAGINN2", "observe")
            if (loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading) {
                Log.d("TAGINN2", "loading")
                // Show loading indicator
            } else {
                Log.d("TAGINN2", "not Loading")
                // Hide loading indicator
                val error = when {
                    loadState.prepend is LoadState.Error -> loadState.prepend as LoadState.Error
                    loadState.append is LoadState.Error -> loadState.append as LoadState.Error
                    loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error -> loadState.refresh as LoadState.Error
                    else -> null
                }

                error?.let {
                    Log.e("TAGINN2", "error occurred $error")
                    // Handle error
                }
            }
        }
        submitDataToAdapter()
    }

    private fun submitDataToAdapter() {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {

            viewModel.flow.collectLatest { pagingData ->
                Log.d("TAGINN2", "submitting data to adapter ${pagingData.toString()}")
                adapter.submitData(pagingData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## WebPagesSearchAdapeter

```
package com.example.browserapp.adapters

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.paging.PagingDataAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.browserapp.R
import com.example.browserapp.dataClasses.bingSearch.WebpagesSearch
import com.example.browserapp.listeners.webpagesListener

class WebpagesSearchAdapter(diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value>) :
    PagingDataAdapter<WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value, WebpagesSearchAdapter.ViewHolder>(diffCallback) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // Inflate the item layout dynamically
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_websearch, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        try {
            val currentItem: WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value? = getItem(position)
            // Bind data to the views in the item layout
            if (currentItem?.thumbnailUrl != null) {
                holder.bindImage(currentItem.thumbnailUrl)
                holder.thumbnailImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE // Show image view
            } else {
                holder.thumbnailImage.visibility = View.GONE // Hide image view
            }
            holder.name.text = currentItem?.name
            holder.displayUrl.text = currentItem?.displayUrl
            holder.datePublished.text = currentItem?.datePublished
            holder.snippet.text = currentItem?.snippet
            webpagesListener(holder.webpageLinearLayout, holder.itemView.context, currentItem?.url)
            // ... (bind other views as needed)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("TAGINN2", e.stackTraceToString())
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        //        name, displayUrl,datePublished,snippet
        // ... (reference other views in the item layout)
        val thumbnailImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImage)
        val name: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name)
        val displayUrl: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.displayUrl)
        val datePublished: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.datePublished)
        val snippet: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.snippet)
        val webpageLinearLayout: LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.webpageLinearLayout)
        fun bindImage(imageUrl: String?) {
            Glide.with(itemView.context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(thumbnailImage)
        }

    }

    companion object {
        val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(
                oldItem: WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value,
                newItem: WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value
            ): Boolean {
                // Return true if items represent the same web page
                val bool = oldItem.url == newItem.url
                Log.d("TAGINN2", "are items the same:$bool")
                return bool
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(
                oldItem: WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value,
                newItem: WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value
            ): Boolean {
                // Return true if items have the same content (name, url, etc.)
                val bool = oldItem == newItem
                Log.d("TAGINN2", "are contents the same:$bool")
                return bool
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## WebPagesViewModel

```
package com.example.browserapp.viewmodels

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.paging.Pager
import androidx.paging.PagingConfig
import androidx.paging.cachedIn
import com.example.browserapp.dataClasses.bingSearch.WebpagesSearch
import com.example.browserapp.paging.WebpagesPagingSource
import com.example.browserapp.search.webSearchEndpoint
import com.example.browserapp.search.getSearchWebResultAsync
import com.example.browserapp.search.searchTerm
import com.example.browserapp.search.subscriptionKey
import com.example.browserapp.search.webpagesCount
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class WebPagesViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var query:String? = null
    private val _webSearchValues = MutableLiveData<WebpagesSearch?>()
    val webSearchValues: LiveData<WebpagesSearch?> = _webSearchValues
    private var isDataFetched = false
    val flow = Pager(
        // Configure Paging behavior
        PagingConfig(pageSize = webpagesCount, prefetchDistance = 5 ) // Example configuration
    ) {
        // Create PagingSource instance when needed
        WebpagesPagingSource(query)
    }.flow
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
//    fun fetchWebSearchResults(query:String) {
//
//        if (!isDataFetched){
//            viewModelScope.launch {
//                val result = getSearchWebResultAsync(query,0)
//                _webSearchValues.postValue(result) // Use postValue for main thread safety
//                if(result !== null){
//                    isDataFetched = true
//                }
//            }
//        }
//    }
}
```

## WebpagesPagingSource

```
package com.example.browserapp.paging

import android.util.Log
import androidx.paging.LoadStates
import androidx.paging.PagingSource
import androidx.paging.PagingState
import com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException
import com.example.browserapp.dataClasses.bingSearch.WebpagesSearch
import com.example.browserapp.search.getSearchWebResultAsync
import com.example.browserapp.search.webpagesCount
import java.io.IOException

class WebpagesPagingSource(
    val query: String?
) : PagingSource<Int, WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value>() {
    override suspend fun load(
        params: LoadParams<Int>
    ): LoadResult<Int, WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value> {
        try {
            // Start refresh at page 1 if undefined.
            val nextPageNumber = params.key ?: 1
            Log.d("TAGINN2", "next page number $nextPageNumber")
            val response = getSearchWebResultAsync(query ?: "", nextPageNumber)
            val data = response?.webPages?.value?.filterNotNull() ?: emptyList()
            val nextKey = if ((response?.webPages?.totalEstimatedMatches != null) &&
                ((response.webPages.totalEstimatedMatches - webpagesCount) > nextPageNumber)
            ) {
                nextPageNumber + 1
            } else {
                null
            }
            Log.d("TAGINN2", "data is $data")
            return LoadResult.Page(
                data = data,
                prevKey = null, // Only paging forward.
                nextKey = nextKey
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // IOException for network failures.
            Log.e("TAGINN2", e.stackTraceToString())
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            Log.e("TAGINN2", e.stackTraceToString())
            // HttpException for any non-2xx HTTP status codes.
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, WebpagesSearch.WebPages.Value>): Int? {

        // Try to find the page key of the closest page to anchorPosition from
        // either the prevKey or the nextKey; you need to handle nullability
        // here.
        //  * prevKey == null -> anchorPage is the first page.
        //  * nextKey == null -> anchorPage is the last page.
        //  * both prevKey and nextKey are null -> anchorPage is the
        //    initial page, so return null.
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }

    }
}
```

I tried many things and the only thing that worked was simulating the button press in the fragment which triggers the onclick listener to open the fragment after a delay which makes sure the data has been retrieved. but also sends my program for an infinite loop